Are these going to become roots on these cuttings? They're taking forever to appear, and I'm worried about the cutting not getting nutrients
I think these cuttings are at least two months old. It's a random bush or perhaps tree that had very nice white flowers. Tomorrow I'll try to go looking to see if I can find the "donor" and identify it.
They seem to be hanging on, but not growing new leaves. Finally, these little white structures appeared up and down the stems in the water. They look root-color-like but are not growing out into actual roots.
Is there any idea what all these white structures are? S
hall I just stick them in soil now and let them decide what they want to do?
I won't be heartbroken if they fail, but at 1 millimeter per month, it seems futile to leave them in water.
Where I live now, it's a real challenge to find something called "rooting compound" that is actually a plant hormone. Folks are chemical-averse here; you can't buy ammonia or peroxide at any normal stores for example. There are some inorganic compounds that one can get online that are said to "promote root growth" but nothing that's an actual plant hormone.




I can not answer your question, but you might be interested in some alternative (natural) sources of rooting hormone.  I have never tried them myself, but willow wood, cinnamon, and aloe vera gel are all supposed to work.  https://www.ruralsprout.com/natural-rooting-hormones/ .  And good luck with your cuttings!

Most things root better in damp sand. vermiculite, or sand-vermiculite mix than they do submerged in water. Even the ones that will manage to make roots in water mostly do better that way.

@Ecnerwal I started with coleus cuttings in water, which are so easy and grow roots like crazy, and so I've just automatically used water for everything else. The advantage is that you can see how they are growing and when they may be ready to pot in soil. This is really great to know, but since these media are not "see-through", how does one know when it's time to pot the cuttings?

One looks for signs of growth, and (not too frequently) gets the cutting out of the pot, media and all as if repotting (ie, act like there might be roots, don't yank it out.) If there are roots, pot on. If there are not roots, put it back in the media and wait some more. Done with care it's similar in stress to removing a cutting from the water to have a look.

@Ecnerwal got it. I love the word "vermiculite" - I used to say it as a kid for fun. Perhaps now, for the first time, I'll actually own some! There's plenty of sand at the beaches here, but I'm not sure how one cleans and sterilizes ocean-beach sand, so I'll ask that as a new question. How to prepare sand from an ocean beach to be suitable for rooting small cuttings?

Those look very much like the start of roots to me.  If you are getting new leaf growth (which I think you are, but the picture is of-course point in time), those are roots - and I'd be considering planting the cuttings in soil.
It is difficult to see, but if the white stuff on the leaf is mold, you want to get onto that.  Maybe wipe down the leaves with bleach / vinegar and keep an eye on it.
If you are wanting to continue to grow the cutting in water for a while longer maybe try blacking it out - I speculate it is possible the light is confusing the rooting structures - certainly the roots don't need any light, and light can't be good for algae etc.
As far as I know, rooting compound is normally applied to the cutting to stimulate the cells to produce roots (ie it is not applied to roots - indeed soil may be beneficial here as it can stimulate the exchange of nutrients between the plant and the soil microbiome).
I would not bother about it here, but there are a few alternatives to chemical rooting hormone which can apparently help.   If you have access to a willow tree you can easily make "willow water" which is probably about as good as commercial rooting hormone, and, I believe, the basis of it.   (Found https://gardentherapy.ca/willow-water-diy-rooting-hormone/ on the subject).     There are a couple of other things people use to stimulate growth - Cinnamon is considered a rooting hormone.  Also honey - although afaict honey is more something to prevent infection then an actual rooting hormone.

This is very helpful, thank you! Yes, some other cuttings have had algal (or worse) growth problems and I've been simply changing the water every week, but blocking as much of the sunlight as possible is an excellent idea. I'll give one of these things a little rub today to make sure it's part of the stem structure and not something growing on it. Also, thanks for the tip on willow water! Now to try to find a wild willow...

as for the dusty mold on the leaves, I'll look around for leaf-safe dilutions of those chemicals before I try it.

I rubbed several of these little white things. They remind me of extremely tiny cauliflowers - the top surfaces rub off and make this little white powder, but the majority of the structure is still solid and firmly attached to the stem.

Given:

enough free space(soil)
easy weekly watering
warm temperatures

there's no advantage to keeping cuttings in water. Just be careful not to damage them when planting.
